# Oracle - Return Invalid Canada Postal codes

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-like

I am trying to run this query which doesn't return any records. I know there are invalid postal codes however it doesn't work.

```
select * 
from ADDR_TAB 
where  ZIPCODE not like ('[ABCEGHJ-NPRSTVXY][0-9][ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z][0-9][ABCEGHJ-NPRSTV-Z][0-9]');
```

Also tried,

```
select * 
from ADDR_TAB 
where  ZIPCODE not like ('[A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9][A-Z][0-9]');
```

Comment: `LIKE` doesn't support regular expressions. You need `regexp_like`. https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions007.htm#SQLRF52141

Answer (score 0):

Well LIKE in SQL (and Oracle) is for matching String.

Here you are trying to match a regex pattern which is different.

You should have a look at the documentation of REGEXP_LIKE of Oracle :
https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/conditions007.htm#SQLRF00501